# How do they get guitars to sound so great on tv?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, microphones, live-sound

When playing acoustic guitar sometimes it is very difficult to hear certain notes or certain slaps or chords. With shows like American Idol or America's Got Talent, for instance this video:

I do not see a microphone anywhere near Klafford’s acoustic guitar yet in this video you can clearly hear his acoustic so well. It cannot be that his voice mic is picking up the strumming patterns of the guitar, or is it?

How can I get an acoustic sound so clear, similar to this video? Here is another example from a singer named Alejandro Aranda from American Idol:

Similarly, you can hear his acoustic sounds very well but I do not see a mic anywhere near his guitar. Both examples don't seem to be playing the acoustic via an amp either. What gives, and what can I use to do something similar? Should I be purchasing a mic for an acoustic guitar?

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the [topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I think this question could benefit from some edits to get at what you "really want." Questions along the lines of "how can I get the sound in this video" are off-topic since they're often too specific or impossible to answer. But "How can I get the best sound from an acoustic guitar, in a stage setting, without putting a mic in front of it" is a great question.

Comment: A couple of points, though: 1) many acoustics have pickups built-in. When the camera zooms in on Alejandro you can see a plug coming from his end pin; since there's no big cable around, it's probably connected to a wireless transmitter. 2) I know many acoustics also pair an internal mic with a pickup for a nice full-spectrum sound as well as good amplification and percussive sound. 3) I wouldn't put it past anything on TV to "sync" to a pre-recorded performance (good enough for The Monkees!)

Comment: @AndyBonner - are you saying these shows already have this "live" performance recorded and they just play it along with whatever the artist is playing "just in case" ?

Comment: Oh, I'm not making serious allegations, just that it wouldn't surprise me if it were revealed. So the answer to "how can this sound *and* look so good at the same time," in general, in TV or videos, is often that it's recorded in a clean environment and then performed to the recording. Even in live shows, various big pop acts have had moments that reveal that they were actually lip-syncing to pre-recorded audio, and with the level of processing involved, it's not much different.

Comment: Built in pick ups are common enough now that you sometimes need to sort through racks of acoustics that _don't_ have them.

Comment: @AndyBonner thank you makes sense i thought after that incident with that one band lip syncing was over but maybe Im too naive.

Comment: @JonH, if you're referring to Milli Vanilli, the issue was that they were lip syncing to a recording of _someone else_. They weren't the real singers, and it turned, had never actually recorded anything themselves ever. It isn't such a problem if an artist lip syncs to their own recording, though it does depend on the venue.

Comment: Thanks @SethR I did not know that, that is really bad lol.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first hint is that they both sound like an 'electro-acoustic' [especially the second one] with an internal piezo-type pickup & the second is you can see the cable out to what is probably a radio transmitter pack taped to the back of the guitar or hidden in the player's clothing.

[image]

[image]

You can pick up a cheap one for not a lot of money on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Schaller-16050101-Oyster-Piezo-Pickup-nickel/dp/B008HLSEJS/ref=sr_1_12?crid=2OXV4VVOZT5JD&keywords=Piezo%20Pickup&qid=1650563421&s=musical-instruments&sprefix=piezo%20pickup%2Cmi%2C69&sr=1-12) or anywhere. Same as most things, you tend to get what you pay for. I doubt the ones the TV show uses are so cheap.
 <sub>I didn't go so far as to try to see exactly what guitar each is using & whether it's already sold with 'plug-in' capability</sub>

You can also get mic systems, either internal or external. The best of these costs as much, or more than, the guitar.
I've used a [DPA 4060](https://www.dpamicrophones.com/lavalier/4060-series-miniature-omnidirectional-microphone) in a similar way [when I was strapped for a mic to use - it's beautiful, but it's an omni so suffers from spill] but ideally, you'd want their [4099](https://www.dpamicrophones.com/4099-core) to do this live.
It doesn't look quite so pretty as an internal, but by heck it sounds good.

Comment: I did not see that cable honestly lol.  So are you saying they are plugged into some sort of AMP?

Comment: Even better, they can be plugged directly into a soundboard somewhere, and that signal is recorded directly.  Show producers can then put whatever effects necessary to make it sound great (or terrible, if you're one of the designated bad acts)

Comment: @Edward thank you ok now i see why live performances and recorded performances are so good. Seems like there is a lot going on behind the scenes I thought I just sucked so bad!

Comment: @JonH playing an instrument well is a skill. Getting it to sound good in a recording, even when played well, is an art form unto itself. There's a reason sound engineers have their own profession.

Comment: If it has pickups or is connected to an amp, how is it an acoustic guitar? // @Edward "designated bad acts"? I had no idea that was a thing. What's the practice called in the industry? (Once I know what it's called,  I can google it.)

Comment: @RosieF - I used to go to 'acoustic open mic nights' where a drumkit was the banned instrument..!

Comment: @RosieF: The term "electric" guitar is used to describe instruments in which the motion of the strings magnetically generates a voltage that is then amplified, without the any meaningful quantity of mechanical energy from the strings having to be transferred to any other part of the instrument.  While it's impossible to completely avoid the transfer of vibrational energy to the body, and such coupling may influence the sound of the instrument, such transfer does not play an essential role in the process of producing a signal.